# Can I use both C# and C++/CLI in a single assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, c++-cli

Can I put together both C# and C++/CLI source files in a single project, and then compile them to obtain a single .DLL assembly?

Comment: In theory they're both converted to MSIL, it *should be possible* but i'm unsure how you would go about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain single DLL from code both in c++/cli and c# using command line tools. Let's assume you have two files: A.cc with C++/CLI code and B.cs with C# code. It should look something like this:

- First compile c++ code into .obj file `cl.exe /MD /c /clr A.cc`
- Compile c# code into "module" adding previously created .obj with /addmodule switch: `csc.exe /target:module /addmodule:A.obj B.cs`
- Then link the module into single DLL: `link.exe /DLL /LTCG /NOENTRY /CLRIMAGETYPE:IJW A.obj B.netmodule`

I haven't tested it but it should work.